# Why don´t enter a funcion in my controller asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to access in my controller but the problem is the next

```
public ResponseDTO uploadImageToAmazon(int uploadImageToAmazon )
{
  return new ResponseDTO { success = false, messagge = "No se pueden realizar los cambios" };

}
```

and dont enter but in the same controller i have this and in this i havent problem

```
public RestaurantPacketDTO GetRestaurantPacket(int restaurantPacketNumber)
{
        IRestaurantManager rm = CoreManager.Instance.GetService<IRestaurantManager>();
       return rm.GetRestaurantPacket(restaurantPacketNumber);
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the actions?

Comment: Are the action annotated?

Comment: like this https://localhost:44302/API/Restaurant?restaurantPacketNumber=1

Answer (score 0):

Restaurant is the controller.

uploadImageToAmazon not match the call semantic of WebAPI.

How are you calling the uploadImageToAmazon method?